# getElementsByTagName problem in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, safari, google-chrome

I`m parsing a Google Maps RSS with javascript and using the following code to get the point coordinates:

point_coords = items.getElementsByTagName('georss:point')

Unfortunately it works in FF but not in safari and chrome (still not tested in Opera and IE)

The XML looks like:

```
<item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">guidNo</guid>
    <pubDate>Mon, 23 Mar 2009 20:16:41 +0000</pubDate>

    <title>title text</title>
    <description><![CDATA[text]]></description>
    <author>UniCreditBulbank</author>
    <georss:point>
      42.732342 23.296659
    </georss:point>
  </item>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I think that you`re both right depending from the browsers, so I`m using a combination of selectors. I`m still unable to make it work everywhere (opera left) but I hope that I`ll figure it out in Monday and show you the solution.

Thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Final solution working in IE6,7,8, FF, Opera, Chrome and Safari

```
point_coords = item.getElementsByTagName('georss:point')[0];
if(!point_coords || point_coords == null){
    point_coords = item.getElementsByTagName('point')[0];
}
if(!point_coords || point_coords == null){
    point_coords = item.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.georss.org/georss', 'point')[0];
}
return point_coords
```

Thanks for all hints they did the job )

Answer (score 3):

Similar problem for me.  `getElementsByTagName` was failing on safari but not Firefox/Internet Exlporer.  Turns out the namespace prefix was needed for Firefox/Internet Explorer and not for Safari so now, according to the agent...

```
getElementsByTagName("iesr:Collection")  // ff/ie

getElementsByTagName("Collection")       // safari
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the tag name for `<georss:point>` is `point`, not `georss:point`. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for the safari implementation.

https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/d16365012e27f514685eb5c365dcb315