# add crossdomain in html

Tags: javascript, xml

I am getting data from xml file when I download xml file on local server it is working fine, but when I am giving online path of xml file it is not working. I read about something about that I think it is a crossdomain issue, but how to call crossdomain file in html .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }



xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.mydomain.com./myfile/xml_9646.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


</script>
```

Comment: may i know reason please

Comment: in flash it is working file but how

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server implement [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) you can

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10083975/295783

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.support.cors = true; // IMPERATIVE for IE(8) support
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml?partnerId=1002&partnerUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.s2d6.com%2Fx%2F%3Fx%3Dc%26z%3Ds%26v%3D3868801%26t%3D",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('...').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).find("...").text();
        // ....

      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the back end of your domain, you could have something like [PHP to read the remote](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx) XML for you. Your server will act like a bridge/proxy for your JS code and the remote XML. Since [JS can't talk over other domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you ask your server (which is in your domain) to read it for you.