# Jquery $.getJSON doesn't work in IE works fine in other browsers

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adapt ajax for crossdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640633/adapt-ajax-for-crossdomain)

I am using following code to read json data from the spring webservice.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/rest/languages/',
function(data) 
{
    $("#lang_1").html(data.languages[0].language);
    $("#lang_2").html(data.languages[1].language);
    $("#lang_3").html(data.languages[2].language); 
});
```

The above snippet works fine in firefox and chrome. It doesn't work in the Internet explorer.

I am using tomcat as a webserver and spring 3.0 rest webservices to generate JSON response.

Please suggest.

Comment: It is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153298/add-crossdomain-in-html. And have limitations http://stackoverflow.com/a/6640760/719323

Comment: An error message instead of "it doesn't work" might be helpful !!

Comment: I am not getting any error message, I guess may be IE doesn't support CORS. Is any alternative is there to achieve this?