# cross-browser 'getElementsByTagName' with namespace from responseXML

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, xml-namespaces, getelementsbytagname

Am trying to read an XML response using `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var rows = items.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("z:row");

for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
{
//do something
}
```

Above code works fine in Firefox and IE but in chrome it throws null.. i mean it does not get any data.. when i `alert` the `rows.length` it gives me `0` always in chrome.

Then i searched in google and understood the issue is with `xsd:element`, then i changed `"z:row"` to only `"row"`. Then it worked in Chrome but Firefox and IE returned `0` for `rows.length`.

Is there any method which across all browsers?

Comment: To make this an even better question, could you please show us the (relevant part of) your XML document?

Comment: see possible duplicate [getElementsByTagName problem in chrome and safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207941/getelementsbytagname-problem-in-chrome-and-safari) or [Parsing XML namespaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083565/parsing-xml-namespaces) for solutions, though they don't answer your exact question.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use:

```
function byTagNS(xml,tag,ns) {
    return xml.getElementsByTagNameNS
      ? xml.getElementsByTagNameNS(ns,tag)
      : xml.getElementsByTagName(ns+":"+tag);
}
```

With in your case:

```
byTagNS(responseXML, "row", "z")
```

Comment: @Bergi nothing! Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the namespace then you could use the following:

```
xml.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "yourElementHere")
```

This will fetch any element with the desired name regardless of which namespace it has or whether it has any namespace at all. Additionally, this should work as expected across different browsers.

[See link for documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagNameNS).