# DOM parsing is not working in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015, xrmservicetoolkit

I'm trying to parse the response from a XMLHttpRequest using XrmServiceToolkit for CRM 2015. The code for parsing the results is working fine in IE 11, however it is not working as expected in Chrome. Please assist.

Here are the details :

```
var requestMain = ""
    requestMain += "      <request i:type=\"b:RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">";
    requestMain += "        <a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
    requestMain += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "            <c:key>Target</c:key>";
    requestMain += "            <c:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
    requestMain += "              <a:Id>" + entityId + "</a:Id>";
    requestMain += "              <a:LogicalName>" + entityName + "</a:LogicalName>";
    requestMain += "              <a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
    requestMain += "            </c:value>";
    requestMain += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "        </a:Parameters>";
    requestMain += "        <a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
    requestMain += "        <a:RequestName>RetrieveRecordChangeHistory</a:RequestName>";
    requestMain += "      </request>";

var changeHistoryResponse = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Execute(requestMain);
var results = changeHistoryResponse.getElementsByTagName("a:Results")[0];

...

var auditRecords = results.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].getElementsByTagName("b:AuditDetail");
```

The line `changeHistoryResponse.getElementsByTagName("a:Results")[0];` is working fine in IE,  however it returns `null` in Chrome. Because of this the other part of the code is throwing error

```
var auditRecords = results.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].getElementsByTagName("b:AuditDetail");
```

> Cannot read property '`childNodes`' of undefined

Comment: Please don't use snippets if the code doesn't actually need to run in the question.

Comment: i think you should use `getElementsByTagNameNS('a:Results')` in chrome if you want to include the namespace,  otherwise you could use `getElementsByTagName('Results')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [cross-browser 'getElementsByTagName' with namespace from responseXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486882/cross-browser-getelementsbytagname-with-namespace-from-responsexml)

Comment: Thanks @Icepickle    getElementsByTagName('Results') worked fine.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Going forward, I will ensure to use sample code instead of snippets. Thanks