# Using getElementsByTagNameNS with namespace alias

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xml-parsing

Is there a possibility to use the javascript method 'getElementsByTagNameNS' by passing the namespace alias instead of the namespace uri?

I'm parsing multiple XML-Documents and search for multitple tags with different namespaces in javascript.

I created the following function related to following [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207941/getelementsbytagname-problem-in-chrome-and-safari):

```
// The node name is passed with namespace e.g. 'c:label'
function getElementsByTagNameCrossBrowser (xmlNode, tagName) {
    var elementCollection, pureTagName, nameSpace;

    elementCollection = xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

    if (elementCollection.length === 0) {
        nameSpace = tagName.split(':')[0];
        pureTagName= tagName.split(':')[1];
        elementCollection = xmlNode.getElementsByTagNameNS(nameSpace, pureTagName);
    }

    return elementCollection;
}
```

In FF and IE this functions provides the correct results, but in Chrome the 'getElementsByTagName' method returns no result when passing a tagName with namespace included.

If I only search for the 'pureTagName' without considering the 'nameSpace' I get too much results.

As I saw in the [MDN-Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagNameNS) the 'getElementsByTagNameNS' method requires the namespace URI, but at the moment I can't access the URI. Is there a workaround or something else to use this method by passing the namespace alias?

Edit:

This is my current Workaraound:

```
function getElementsByTagNameChromeNamespace (xmlNode, tagName) {
    var elementCollection, pureTagName, i, tmpNode, tmpNodeName, resultingCollection;

    // If there is no namespace return normal collection.
    if (tagName.indexOf(':') === -1) {
        return xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    }

    resultingCollection = [];
    pureTagName = tagName.split(':')[1];

    elementCollection = xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(pureTagName);

    for (i = 0; i < elementCollection.length; i++) {
        tmpNode = elementCollection[i];
        tmpNodeName = tmpNode.nodeName;

        if (tmpNodeName === tagName) {
            resultingCollection.push(tmpNode);
        }
    }

    return resultingCollection;
},

function getElementsByTagNameCrossBrowser (xmlNode, tagName) {
    var elementCollection;

    elementCollection = xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

    if (elementCollection.length === 0) {
        elementCollection = this.getElementsByTagNameChromeNamespace(xmlNode, tagName);
    }

    return elementCollection;
}
```